# Displaying flow direction using arrow in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, spatial-analyst, hydrology, flow-direction

I created a **flow direction raster** out of a DEM using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst Tools/ Hydrology, so the directions are coded in raster values as displayed below.

[image]

[http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/flow-direction.htm]

Then, changing the layer style in the Layer Properties to an arrow, I **cannot set the right orientation** as coded by the ArcGIS flow direction tool (first image). So as you see in the second image, the arrows don't indicate the right direction, which should actually lead to the sink (blue polygon).

Instead of using the layer properties tried the "Utility Network Analyst Toolbar", but the flow direction raster layer cannot be selected.

Can anyone help me where to adjust the orientation of the arrows?

[image]

Comment: Create lookup table, join to flow direction, use lookup tool to create new raster with bearings.